# Android app for recording raw data (eg RINEX) from bluetooth GNSS receiver

Tags: gps, gis, land-surveying

I have a Sparkfun Surveyor (GNSS), which my phone connects to via Bluetooth. ([product details](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/18443))

[image]

I would like to record raw GNSS (~GPS) data, in order to do post processing on a PC. I believe RINEX is the most common format for this.

I can find several apps (eg [Geo++ RINEX Logger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.geopp.rinexlogger)) that offer recording RINEX, but only for the internal GNSS built into the phone.

I am looking for an app that lets me record RINEX from this external GNSS.

Comment: If you don't get an answer I would try to find an open source app that is able to display the position from your Sparkfun Surveyor. May be the author(s) or the community can help you to extend it to write the received data into a file.

Comment: @Robert: Thanks. However, I solved my problem in a different way, without actually using an app. The device takes an SD-card, and I configured it to log raw data (RAWX format) to the SD-card.